# I didnt quite get the "there exist a j"part. Can anyone help me understand it better?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

[image]

## I didnt quite get the "there exist a j"part. Can anyone help me understand it better?

Comment: It is explained in the parenthesis afterwards. By the way you should at least take the time of typing the question you don't understand... You could rephrase it as "the boundary is made by all points such that".

Comment: My bad. I&#39;ll keep that in mind. But I still didn&#39;t quite get it. Does it mean that for a  cube, a boundary will be collection of values represented by Xj and that value of Xj will either be between 0 and 0.05 or 0.95 and 1 and atleast one Xj will have value in the extreme 10% i.e; between 0.95 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

For each dimension, the most extreme 10% are categorized as boundary. The collection of all points which lie in the most extreme 10% of any dimension is classified as the boundary set.

for a 1D line: fraction of points in boundary `f = 0.100`

for a 2D square: `f = 0.1 + 2*(0.05-2*0.05**2) = 0.190`. To see why, you can draw a square with cutting lines at the `0.05` and `0.95` fractions for each of the 2 dimensions. You will end up with:
[image: this]

for a 3D cube: `f = 0.1 + #I'm too lazy to write it all down = 0.271`

for a 50D hypercube (definitely not going to write the direct calculation): `f = 0.995`.

Now luckily there is an indirect way of calculating these fractions which requires significantly less effort. I'll leave that bit of homework for you to do.